# What does "You sir are a idoit" mean as someone's name (at stackoverflow.com at least)?

Tags: support

I hope this is not a dumb question, but in the Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602033/whats-the-difference-between-double-quotes-and-single-quote-in-c) the name shown as the OP is "You sir are a idoit".

Now I know that anyone can name themselves what they want, but the fact that there is no picture, rating, or acceptance rate, and the name is not a link to anyone's page makes me believe something else must be going on than just someone naming themselves weirdly.

So what is going on in this case?

Comment: Means they can't spell "idiot". :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: It also means they don't know when to use "an".

Comment: Exquisitely ironic.

Comment: ([The duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295805/) offers a much better explanation.)

Comment: There's [a lot of words that they can't spell correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/602033/timeline#history_b7a53e5c-25d9-4a51-9f6e-a4a9f2afc50e), their user name *might* not be one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means the account no longer exists.

Comment: Could the question also have been migrated?

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks. I really was confused at first :)

Comment: @Sam it *could* but in this case *doesn't*