# Why is this non-anonymous username on this non-migrated question greyed out and not a link?

Tags: support, display-names

There are [several reasons why a username might not be a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290627/172266).  The user may have been deleted, the post may have been migrated, or a few other reasons.

None of those seem to apply to [this post on Bicycles.SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/4410/2916).  The username appears grey and is not a link, but it is not anonymous either and the question was not migrated.  Why is the username in this case not a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User names were not always anonymised (changed back to user_xxx) when deleted, that has been added somewhere along the way, few years ago, but pretty sure that after 2011.

So users deleted before that still "keep" their original name, just grayed out and unclickable, since there is no profile to link to.

Comment: There's a user on Super User from way back who was prolific. Stuff's moved on from when she posted, but I still feel a *bit* strange about deleting her old posts. Its like deleting a small bit of SU history from before my time.

Comment: @Journeyman why delete? Shouldn't closing old questions that are not on topic anymore be enough? And answers which are out dated shouldn't be deleted either IMO, maybe add a comment or edit, but don't think it should be removed.

Comment: Answers mostly and they are often link  only and broken

Comment: @Journeyman oh, I see. Well... she got lots others so guess it's fine. :-)